# foreach loop with key in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

In the following foreach loop, how would I access the value of $url?

```
 foreach ( $this->sessions as $i => $url )
      curl_multi_add_handle( $mh, $this->sessions[$i] );
 …
```

I am trying to understand how that value for the url would be accessed for each particular cycle of the loop.

Comment: You would simply use `$url` within the loop, what's the issue?

Answer (score 5):

You just use the variable:

```
foreach ( $this->sessions as $i => $url ) {
    curl_multi_add_handle( $mh, $url );
}
```

Also, get in the habit of always putting braces around the body of `for`, `foreach`, `if`, `while`, etc., even if it's just one line. It prevents difficult-to-find errors in the future.